# How to convert Maven repos to Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have two repositories in my `pom` file

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-app-releases</id>
        <name>My App First releases repository</name>
        <url>http://myapp.artifactoryonline.com/myapp/first-server-releases</url>
    </repository>
        <repository>
        <id>my-app-snapshots</id> 
        <name>My App First snapshots repository</name>
        <url>http://myapp.artifactoryonline.com/myapp/first-server-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

My Gradle version

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    myAppReleases {
        url: 'http://myapp.artifactoryonline.com/myapp/first-server-releases'
    }
    myAppSnapshots {
        url: 'http://myapp.artifactoryonline.com/myapp/first-server-snapshots/'
    }
}
```

When I start to `sync` Gradle says

```
Error:(25, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: myAppReleases()!
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = myAppReleases
        url = 'http://myapp.artifactoryonline.com/myapp/first-server-releases'
    }
    maven {
        name = myAppSnapshots
        url = 'http://myapp.artifactoryonline.com/myapp/first-server-snapshots/'
    }
}
```